# How can I record a video signal in Linux from the command line?

Tags: linux, video, vlc-media-player, libav

I have a Linux machine with a Pinnacle video card. I wanna record a video signal from my TV connected to the S-Video input in my Pinnacle card. I could record using VLC GUI, but I wanna cron it, so I need to use some command line program like avconv or maybe with the vlc command line. In my case the display input (S-Video) is 3. Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's a link to the commands along with images to help

http://askubuntu.com/questions/329852/recording-a-video-podcast-at-a-certain-time-using-vlc-or-another-program-like

Comment: Here's a link to the commands along with images to help

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/329852/recording-a-video-podcast-at-a-certain-time-using-vlc-or-another-program-like][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/329852/recording-a-video-podcast-at-a-certain-time-using-vlc-or-another-program-like

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the command line interface of VLC, `cvlc`. Here is an example for saving a stream into a file:

`cvlc http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okqEVeNqBhc --sout='#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}:std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=/home/user/video.mpg}'`

You only need to change the link to your input device.